# Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, phonegap, android-assets

I am using PhoneGap for a mobile app. The software is Alpha Anywhere, if that matters.

Here is the error message:

```
Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
Source file:///android_asset/www/javascript/a5.js
Line:: 184
Column: 134

Stack:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at HTMLHtmlElement.wFunc(file:///android_asset/www/javascript/a5.js:184:134)
```

This was generated from Phonegap, I have never touched the a5.js script. The only time I ever get an error is when I'm testing my app on a mobile device, the only one I have so far tested it on is Android. Here is the code with the specific function that is erroring:

```
......

var evntScope = arguments[3]?arguments[3]:null;

......

if($e.loaded) {
   var ele = $(evntEle);

   if(!ele) return false;
   var cScope = (scopeOverride)?evntScope:ele;

   var wFunc = function(e) {
      return evntFunc.call(cScope, $e.getEvent(e), evntScope);
   };

  ......
```

This is where evntFunc is 1st declared, which is directly above line 184..

```
$e._cee(this,e);}}}}},

cee:function(ele,e) {
    var evnts = $e._cei[ele.id].e[e.customData.type];
    if(evnts) {
        for(var i=0; i<evnts.length; i++)
            evnts[i][1](e);
    }
},

add:function(evntEle,evntType,evntFunc) {
    var evntScope = arguments[3]?arguments[3]:null;
    var scopeOverride = typeof arguments[4] == 'boolean'?arguments[4]:false;
    var groupName = arguments[5]?arguments[5]:'';

    if(evntEle && evntEle.length && !evntEle.tagName && typeof evntEle! = 'string' && !evntEle.alert && typeof evntEle[0] != 'undefined') {
       var returnBool = true;

       for(var i=0; i<evntEle.length; i++) {
           returnBool=(($e.add(evntEle[i],evntType,evntFunc,evntScope,scopeOverride,groupName)) && returnBool)
       }

    return returnBool;
}
```

The specific function is .call following evntFunc.call - I expanded the code so it is easier to read
Thoughts? This is generated, not really sure how to fix the error or what the event is exactly doing. If you need the rest of the code where this completely starts and completely ends I can get it. Thank you in advance.

---

Edit: Added evntFunc declaration.. the last return returnBool is line 183.

Comment: The error message says that `evntFunc` is `undefined`. It's impossible to see why that's the case from the code provided.

Comment: where `evntFunc` come from? Can you provide it?

Comment: @VLAZ I added where evntFunc is right above.. Sorry I meant to include that in my original post. Thanks for both of you for responding.